# How to start a visualisation server for python database

Tags: python, database, flask

I have a database test.db produced by the python module pyABC and the command to see a web-based visualisation of the database is by using the following command in a terminal window:

```
abc-server Downloads/Code/test.db
```

It appears to not give any errors but no webpage appears. Any thought as to what I might be missing?

```
 (base) YYYY@MMMMM ~ % abc-server Downloads/Beth/Code/test.db 
 * Serving Flask app "pyabc.visserver.server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: What happens exactly when you open the URL?

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for a quick reply, and for pointing out I need to open the URL (sorry I didn't realise this; stoopid error). I asked the question originally because I didn't realise I had to copy and paste that url but even so, the db appears to be empty. According to the documentation, it suggests it display data on-the-fly but the db seems empty. https://pyabc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web_visualization.html . Do you think I should ask a specific question about this on the forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short documentation of the pyABC web server can be found at https://pyabc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/visualization.html#web-based-visualizations. If no data are shown, it can be because the file is empty. To check this, tools such as `sqlitebrowser`, `sqlite3` or the pyABC data access API https://pyabc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_datastore.html can be used.

Comment: It would be better to add some citation from the given links. Web pages can change and make the answer irrelevant in the future

Comment: In principle yes, thanks for pointing out. Here, the provided tools should suffice for checking database content, while the links should be regarded rather as further information in case the underlying question is of a more open nature.